# Soap XML is different between two machines

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, soap1.2

I've started my .net service on two machines (one is Windows server 2012 and the other one is Windows 7). The service uses the same compiled c# code on each machine.

On the windows server the xml response create a xmlns and calls it "a" and puts it on all the attributes in the xml.

On the windows 7 it uses the default namespace that is on the top attribute.

example:

```
windows server 2012
<postResponse xmlns:a="xxxxx">
    <a:line1> 
        <a:line2> bla </a:line1>
        <a:line3> bla </a:line1>
        <a:responseCode> 200 </a:responseCode>
    </a:line1>
</postResponse> 

windows 7
<postResponse>
    <line1 xmlns:"xxxxx"> 
        <line2> bla </line1>
        <line3> bla </line1>
        <responseCode> 200 </responseCode>
    </line1>
</postResponse>
```

As it turns out the legacy application that sends me the data notices the difference and doesn't accept the windows server format.
I'm using soap 12 over WCF and the .config files are the same. Why is this happening and where do I find the configuration to fix this?

Comment: Unclear. If it sends the data then why should it care about the format? And always post full error messages.

Comment: The xml files appear to be equivalent. And valid.